# Caption of figures and tables not centered in AMS classes

Tags: tables, floats, captions, amsbook, bugs

According to [AMS Author Handbook](http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/amscls-doc/Author_Handbook_Mono.pdf) the caption of tables and figures should be automatically centered, but for some reason they are moved to the right side.

- This is a screenshot of the Handbook:

[image: Screenshot of a table in AMS Author Handbook]

- This is a screenshot of what I get with the same code:

[image]

- This is my minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{amsbook}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
    \caption{This is a table}
    \begin{tabular}{cccc}
        1&2&3&4\\
        5&6&7&8\\
        9&10&11&12
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

I need to use `amsbook` class (it is in the format of my thesis); therefore, using packages like `caption` should be avoided (AMS manual recommend that). Other AMS classes have the same problem.

Comment: The caption is centered, but the table isn't. Add `\centering` after `\begin{table}`

Comment: By using your code, I got the desired output, check your version of TeX...

Comment: @MadyYuvi I will try a clean install

Comment: @MadyYuvi I reinstall MiKTeX from its oficial page, it still don't work for me.

Comment: @egreg The caption is not centered, but the table is (in the full page it is clear). AMS Handbook states excplicitly that `\centering` is not necessary in any AMS class. Moreover, I already tried and it doesn't solved the problem.

Comment: Oh, sorry! I misread the situation. It's a problem with AMS classes that showed up after the last LaTeX release.

Comment: @BenjamínBaeza Hope I misunderstood your problem, you need the caption should be centered to the table width, am I correct???

Comment: @MadyYuvi yes, I need both of them centered (as it should be according to the documentation)

Comment: @egreg Oh! Then I just have to wait for them to solve it? Hope they update it before I end my thesis. I will use `caption` meanwhile

Comment: The next release will be out in about a month but the fix is already available (in texlive, I don't know about miktex) if you use pdflatex-dev Or you can use the fix that I suggested in the linked question before we updated the sources

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thank! I will use the fix you suggested in the linked question meanwhile.